# Send authenticated mails via Outlook through R using mailR package

Tags: r, outlook, smtp

How can I send mails from R via Outlook?

I was told to use the `sendmailR` package, but I could not figure out how to specify [certain control settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52840058/what-control-settings-are-valid-to-send-automated-emails-from-outlook-using-s) (such as port, username and password). I was also redirected to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2885660/how-to-send-an-email-with-attachment-from-r-in-windows), but it did not help.

I switched to the `mailR` package. I can send mails from other servers, such as `smtp.gmail.com`, but I do not know the Outlook server details. What are the protocol, server and port details required to send mails via Outlook using `mailR`?

Comment: Doest this question refers to (a) sending email message to any SMTP server, to (b) the Microsoft Outlook service on the Internet or just to (c) inserting a message into a Windows application's (MS Outlook) queue (possibly PST/OST file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out. Try this:

```
send.mail(from = "username@custom.org",
          to = c("recipient1@custom.org", "recipient2@custom.org"),
          subject = "Title",
          body = "Hello from R.",
          authenticate = TRUE,
          smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.office365.com",
                  port = 587,
                  user.name = "username@custom.org",
                  passwd = "Pa55w0rd",
                  tls = TRUE))
```

It is a common misconception that the port is 25 or 447. I believe port 25 can only be used when`authenticate = FALSE`.

Many sources claim that the correct server is `smtp-mail.outlook.com`. Perhaps you could try this in the event that the code does not work. Moreover, do not use `ssl = TRUE`. It has to be `tls = TRUE`.

Shoutout to Rahul Premraj's answer to [this archived 2014 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22978369/fail-to-send-email-via-outlook-com-using-mailr-package).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `DescTools::SendOutlookMail()`

```
library(DescTools)
SendOutlookMail(to = c("me@microsoft.com", "you@rstudio.com"), 
                subject = "Some Info", 
                body = "Hi all\r Find the files attached\r Regards, Dude", 
                attachment = c("C:/temp/fileA.txt", 
                               "C:/temp/fileB.txt"))
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the following error:<checkErrorInfo> 80020009 
No support for InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo
checkErrorInfo -2147352567
Error: Exception occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
In RDCOMClient::getCOMInstance(app) :
  creating a new instance of Outlook.Application rather than connecting to existing instance.

Comment: Did you check, that all the attachments exist? Try with a working email address, subject and body only and report.